# Need to add drawing on top of a preexisting drawing in the same frame/panel

Tags: java, swing, drawing, java-2d, paintcomponent

I basically have a matrix of Rectangles and want to draw them separately, but each one drawn deletes any previous one and I end up with one last lonely rectangle. And I've been googling for hours and searching and the only advice I found was draw it all at once, which I tried but seems to completely ruin my listeners which were built around having separate components each.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JComponent;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GraphicEdge extends JComponent
{

    public Rectangle box;
    private Edge edge;
    /**
     * Creates a graphical box corresponding to the given edge at the given 
     * position
     * @param x x coordinate 
     * @param y y coordinate
     * @param e edge represented
     */
    public GraphicEdge(int x, int y, int width, int length, Edge e)
    {
        this.edge = e;
        this.box = new Rectangle(x, y, width, length);
    }
    /**
     * Paints said edge. Will be recalled whenever the edge switches from 
     * active to inactive.
     * @param g graphics.
     */

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        if (this.edge.getActive()==0)
        {
            g2.setColor(Color.red);
        }
        else
        {
            g2.setColor(Color.green);
        }
        g2.fill(this.box);
        g2.draw(this.box);

    }
    /**
     * Calls for the redrawing of the component.
     */
    public void redrawComponent()
    {
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Gets edge.
     */
    public Edge getEdge()
    {
        return this.edge;
    }
    /**
     * Returns the edge's rectangle.
     * @return
     */
    public Rectangle getBox()
    {
        return this.box;
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I don't see where you call the super's `paintComponent(...)` method in your override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you basically want to make your drawings in `paintComponent` persistent?

Well by default all drawings done in `paintComponent` are not persistent.

Thus on `repaint()` `paintComponent` will be called again and draw whatever the method tells it too.

So to solve your problem:

1) Create an `List` inside your class which extends `JPanel` (not `JComponent` unless for a reason).

2) Make a `public` method to allow adding to the List (and removing if needed).

3) In `paintComponent` iterate through the `List` and draw each object.

Here is an example (click with mouse anywhere on container to draw a `Rectangle`):

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    private final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private final MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private List<Rectangle> recs = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                super.mouseClicked(me);
                addRec(new Rectangle(me.getPoint().x, me.getPoint().y, 100, 50));
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void addRec(Rectangle rec) {
        recs.add(rec);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (Rectangle rec : recs) {
            g2d.drawRect(rec.x, rec.y, rec.width, rec.height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }
}
```

NB As @HFOE has said please remember to call `super.paintComponent(g)` as first call in overridden `paintComponent` to honor the *paint chain* or visual anomalies could occur.